# Bool toggling while KeyDown?

Tags: c#, winforms

So here's the problem. I'm using the keyDown event to set a bool to true - and as long as it's true, the mouseMove event paints on a picturebox. Essentially a drawing program. Problem is that as long as I'm holding down the drawing button, the bool seems to toggle on and off, and I get a weird stripey result (see blue line in sample picture). The bool doesn't get turned off in code, so I have no idea what's causing it (well, it gets turned off, but I disabled that part of the code and am still getting the problem).

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is some of the code. I left out the keyUp event because I can disable it and still get the same issue. Even more interestingly, if I let go of the keyboard button, I get a solid straight line, but as long as I hold down the button, it works fine for about a second and then starts doing the stripey thing (similarily to when you hold a button down in text - it waits a bit, then starts repeating the character).

```
private void Main_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string clicked = e.KeyData.ToString().ToLower(); // I'm comparing the clicked key to make sure the right button is clicked (there's a controls changing system)
        cursorLocation = pictureBox1.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);

        if (clicked == ctkey && MapLoaded)
        {
                readyForDraw();
                pen = new Pen(Color.DodgerBlue, penSize);
        }
        else if (clicked == tkey && MapLoaded)
        {
                readyForDraw();
                pen = new Pen(Color.Red, penSize);
        }
        else if (clicked == neutralkey && MapLoaded)
        {
                readyForDraw();
                pen = new Pen(neutralColour, penSize);
        } 
    } 

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDrawing && MapLoaded && addPlayerMode == false)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, cursorLocation, e.Location);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            pictureBox1.Image = mainBitmap;

            cursorLocation = pictureBox1.PointToClient(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
        } 
    }   

private void readyForDraw()
    {
        g = Graphics.FromImage(mainBitmap);            
        isDrawing = true;
        saveBackup();
    }
```

Sample picture. Red is drawn using the MouseDown event - works fine. Blue is the keyDown event, broken.

[image: http://imgur.com/r8AHlh0]

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?  It sounds like you're catching keyup events fired to do automatic key repetition, but that doesn't make sense for what I've seen...  You might want to try to capture slightly lower-level events, but again, WPF or WinForms (or Silverlight or WinRT XAML :-) )

Comment: Can you provide your exact code? It could be anything..

Comment: Winforms, I put it in the tags but forgot title =P

I'll try to post some code tonight, but there are a lot of different functions so it's hard to tell what's relevant and what isn't. I guess I have to just start removing them one by one until the bloody thing works, and then see what broke it.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the wait, Ive been busy. Edited the first post with more accurate info and some of the code. I tried to leave out the really irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Keyboard.GetKeyStates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.getkeystates.aspx) from WPF like so:

```
public static bool IsDown(Key key) {
  return Keyboard.GetKeyStates(key) & KeyStates.Down != 0;
}
```

and it should work without problems even if your app is WinForms and not WPF.
(Reference PresentationCore.dll from your project)